# Find and Replace only numbers and 3rd number in the string using sed

Tags: bash, sed

In a huge file i have port numbers like

```
"port": "7733",
"port": "7734",
"port": "7631",
"port": "7833",
"port": "7835",
"port": "7335",
"port": "9834",
```

I just have to replace(only 3rd number) 3 with 5 using sed.  the intended result should be like

```
"port": "7753",
"port": "7754",
"port": "7651",
"port": "7853",
"port": "7855",
"port": "7355",
"port": "9854",
```

I have tried

```
sed -E 's/[0-9][0-9]3[0-9]+/[0-9][0-9]5[0-9]/g'
```

but this will replace all numbers to [0-9][0-9]5[0-9].

Please let me know how can we achieve using sed

Answer (score 0):

`sed` allows you to save the text that matched a regex as a group to be used later.  This solution saves two groups: the numbers before the `3` and the numbers after.  The replacement text thus consists of the first group, denoted `\1`, the number `5`, and the second group, denoted `\2`.  Thus:

```
$ sed -E 's/([0-9][0-9])3([0-9]+)/\15\2/g' file
"port": "7753",
"port": "7754",
"port": "7651",
"port": "7853",
"port": "7855",
"port": "7355",
"port": "9854",
```

Answer (score 0):

If you data contains 4 digit ports then using `awk` you can just split the field and add 20 to it:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""}{$4+=20}1' file
"port": "7753",
"port": "7754",
"port": "7651",
"port": "7853",
"port": "7855",
"port": "7355",
"port": "9854",
```

Once the output looks good, you can re-direct to another file. Alternatively if you are using GNU awk v4.1 or later you can make changes in place by doing:

```
awk -i inplace 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""}{$4+=20}1' file
```